# How to pull a git repo from github with all unlinked commits

Tags: git, github

I'm wondering how to pull a repo with all of the commits that have not been gc'd, if that is possible..

is it something like:

```
$ git clone x
$ cd x
$ git fetch origin -f
```

? or something else?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe if we know why you need this, we can give you a better answer. Normally the owner of the remote repository will reference commits that they want to be fetchable. Dangling commits that haven't been gc'd are at risk to be lost at any time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770127/dangling-commit-on-remote-git-repos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no command I'm aware of which says "bring down all commit objects in the remote repository, even those that are unreferenced".

You can only bring commits with a reference in the remote repository. You can do this with the command:

```
git fetch [remote] [remoteBranch]:[localBranch]
```

The remote repository will need to create a reference to any dangling commits before you can fetch them.  If you have access to the remote repository, you can do this with a command like:

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

The output will show you any dangling commits. Give them a reference with `git branch [branchname] [commit sha1]`, then you can fetch them.